# How to add an unselectable separator to a combobox in SWT

Tags: combobox, swt

A combobox in our application should show fixed-width and non-fixed-widths font names. I want to add an unselectable separator between them:

```
-- Fixed-width fonts --
Courier New
Lucida Console
...
-- Non-fixed-width fonts --
Arial
...
```

Is that possible with SWT?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. Neither `Combo` nor `CCombo` allow to flag items as unselectable.

But it should be possible to implement a custom combo widget that can show unselectable items with reasonable effort.

If you look into the [`CCombo` code](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Custom%20Widgets/common/org/eclipse/swt/custom/CCombo.java) you will see that it is not a native widget but composed of other SWT widgets. It uses a `List` as the drop-down control to display the items.

If you use a `ScrolledCompposite` for the drop-down widget, you could place `Label`s therein to represent items. Unselectable items wouldn't require extra work. For selectable items, you could use mouse listeners for the `Label`s to highlight them when hovered and to handle selection.

If you plan to show a large number of items (which you shouldn't anyway in a combo box), the number of created labels may have a performance impact.

Alternatively, you may want to try the [Nebula TableCombo](https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/tablecombo/tablecombo.php). Possibly the table can be tweaked to show some items as unselectable (using custom-drawn items) and the selection behavior can be disabled for those.